# Suggestions for Rendering Custom Drawn Shapes for React Web App

Tags: reactjs, shapes, css-shapes

I am at the beginning of creating my own personal React Web App, and I would like to first start by creating a custom trapezoidal (Nothing too complex) shape to use all over the front page.

I researched many methods and libraries that could help (Konva, draw-shape-reactjs, etc.); however, I would like to ask for other opinions about what to use. I did see somewhere that React does not work well with HTML Canvas. So I'll avoid that, unless told otherwise.

If I should consider a simpler way to create such shapes with CSS on a React Framework, please let me know.